# Split list in foreach loop to add new line each iteration

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I want to print all the data line by line where each line contains "n" number of digits, n being user defined.
Something like:

```
void Print(List<int> list, int charactersPerLine)
{
  // TODO: magic here
}
```

Usage

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
Print(list, 4);
```

Desired output:

```
1234
5678
```

So far I tried:

```
List.AddRange(array);
List.Add(array2);
List.Add(array3);
foreach (int i in List)
{
     Console.Write("{0}", i);
}
```

and when the loop writes to the console everything in the `List<int>` is written in a line, and the output is like:

```
12345678
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: put a carriage return after the `{0}`.  So `"{0}\n"`.

Comment: So is your list `{1234, 5678}` or `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`?  If it;s the latter how do you define "iteration"?

Comment: well im adding other arrays to the list to populate. So to be 100% honest im not sure. I will add the extra code that populates the list. All the arrays are populated by integers.

Comment: I'll just leave this [link](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=c%23+print+new+line&oq=c%23+print+new+line&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+console+new+line) over here ...

Comment: @aleksey.berezan thanks buddy but thats not the problem, i know how to add a new line i just cant seem to get the output of the code above to write a new line. Thanks though :)

Comment: @user3352356, ok, I got question wrong. Do you want to print all the data line-by-line where each line contains 4-digits?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan i want to print all the data line by line where each line contains "n" number of digits, n being user defined.

Comment: @user3352356, ok, I suggested the edit to the question, 'cause it was a little bit confusing to me

Comment: @aleksey.berezan sorry for confusion thank you buddy

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
foreach (int i in List)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
}
```

If your input is in `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` format you have to use some condition when to use `Console.WriteLine()` or `Console.Write()`

```
const int LineCharacterLimit = 4;

int i = 0;    
foreach (int i in List)
{
   i++;
   if (i == LineCharacterLimit)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
      i=0;
   }
   else 
   {
      Console.Write("{0}", i);
   } 
}
```

Comment: The problem then is i get one number per line?

Answer (score 1):

You could use String Builder first.  Then just put a `\n` after each line.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
int count = 1;

foreach (int i in List)
{

     str.Append(i.ToString());

     if(count%4 ==0)
        str.Append("\n");
     count++;
} 

Console.Write(str.ToString());
```

Comment: You can use str.AppendLine() instead of Append("\n")

Comment: hmmm tried this no joy :( this has been driving me nuts for hours lol

Comment: Someone said to me at school earlier that if i use a class then i can treat all the different arrays as unique then write to the console treating them as separate. So the writeline would then be Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i.array, i.array2, i.array3); But i have no idea how to do that. I know how to create a class but then dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

More generic version:

```
static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize) 
    {
        int currentBatchSize = 0;
        List<T> batch = new List<T>();

        foreach (var e in source)
        {
            batch.Add(e);

            if (++currentBatchSize % batchSize == 0)
            {                
                yield return batch;
                batch.Clear();
            }            
        }
        yield return batch;
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can find something like this in `morelinq` package.

Usage:

```
static void Print(List<int> list, int charactersPerLine)
{
    foreach (var batch in list.Batch(charactersPerLine)) 
    {
        var strBatch = batch.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", strBatch));
    }
}
```